# Why can't I get a local server running using the http-server in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, httpserver

[Here is an image of the node_modules folder with all the packages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRMbs.png)I am trying to run a local server to make some basic request to interact with my mobile app im developing. I seem to have all the correct packages/dependencies installed yet I can't get the server to run. When I try to run "node http-server" on the command line it keeps outputting this error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/colors'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous>   (/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/nodegang/node_modules/colors/safe.js:8:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

I have installed and reinstalled nodejs about three times to no avail. And I have that colors module install in the node_modules folder yet im getting a message saying it cannot find it? Can anyone help point me in the right direction to getting the server working correctly?

Comment: Can you show us your package.json and you code where you init your server. Also does it run if you try it without that Colors module?

Comment: Do you mean the package.json for the http-module? And I ran the command in terminal using command line. There's no front-end code I just can't seem to get the http-module working to run a server.

Comment: So you have "your" JS file which is importing the colors module, or one of your plugin is pointing to colors module and not you?

Comment: can you please also mention which colors plugin you have installed. Is it installed using "npm install colors"

Comment: How do you create your folder structure? You need run some command setup Nodejs projects, then you will have package.json with all your packages and setup and you have your main js file like index.js or server.js (what ever you call it). And you need to run "node server.js(or whatever you call it)" to start your server.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the dilemma. I had about 6 or 7 incomplete packages so the solution was to delete each of these packages, including the colors package, and install them again. As someone who spent over 4 hours looking for an answer, I advise you to make sure all your packages are updated, complete, and if possible in the same folder for better management!

Answer (score -1):

This problem does not relate to `node_modules`. It looks like a script in `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js` is require `internal/modules/cjs/lib/colors.js`

You should check file `internal/modules/cjs/lib/colors.js` already exist?

Comment: OK, I am not that experienced with nodejs (hence my problem). How do I check for this to see if its a duplicate? I appreciate your insight. However I dont know where to look.

Comment: That one is not an answer too. Wait until you can make comments.